# How do I run my Python script using Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle

I'm trying to get my script to run when I press a button on my UI, not sure how to get it to work. Any ideas?

Example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def OpenPro1():

    print("Hej")

button_1 = Button(root, text = "Hejdå", command = OpenPro1)

button_1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Instead of it printing a text I want it to run a program!

Comment: ...call the appropriate function? If you want `OpenPro1` to do something other than `print("Hej")`, then just **change it**!

Comment: If you want to see the result, look at the terminal window

Comment: If you want to run a program that is in a separate file in a separate process, use subprocess, the same as from a non-tkinter process.  There are several SO Q & A about subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

Your text must account for the unicode characters:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def OpenPro1():
    print("Hej")

button_1 = Button(root, text = u'Hejd\xe5', command = OpenPro1)
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def OpenPro1():

    print("Hej")

    execfile('anyfile.py') #write any file with .py extension.This method is similar to rightclick and open

button_1 = Button(root, text = "Hejdå", command = OpenPro1)

button_1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```